# Jquery Selector: Count element with attribute on the second tr

Tags: jquery, attributes, count, selector, tr

I would like to know how to get the number of element with a certain attribute on the second TR.

What I tried:

```
$("[Chk_RPQSelection_col=1] tr:nth-child(2)").length

$("tr:nth-child(2) [Chk_RPQSelection_col=1] ").length
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no spaces in the selector :

```
$('tr:nth-child(2)[Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"]').length
```

will find all TR's that are the second children of a table looking like

```
<table>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr> <!-- this one -->
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="3"></tr>
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"></tr> <!-- and this one -->
    <tr Chk_RPQSelection_col="4"></tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

to count TD's with that attribute inside the second TR, you can do:

```
$('tr:nth-child(2)').find('td[Chk_RPQSelection_col="1"]').length
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that dosen't fully anwer my question, I misslead my question. In my TR, I have multiple TD, and that's the TD who have the attribute im looking for to count.
so I have <table><tr><td></td><td attr=1></td><td attr=1></td></tr><table>.
So I want to count every TD with the attribute on the second TR of a certain table.

Comment: Managed to make it work!

$('#Information tr:nth-child(2) td[Chk_RPQTotal_col=1]').length;

Thank you!